# Can't resolve 'module' in 'node_modules/natives'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3

I got an error while I am trying to import S3 npm package into my React JS project.

npm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

**Error**

```
./node_modules/natives/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'module' in 'path_to_proj/node_modules/natives'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see how `natives` has anything to do with the linked package. Can you be more specific on what you're doing?

Comment: I just run 'npm install --save s3' in my react js project.